# du report wrong usage and root folder is so big

Tags: debian, logs, root, disk-usage, trash

In Debian the `/root/` directory is so big but `du` show nothing inside it. `root` account is just a supervisor/administrator/superuser user, there is no folder for this account in home directory. This extra account created just for supervision is installed by default in Debian.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon, or by adding a line containing three backticks before AND after the text.

Comment: You should not be logging in to a desktop environment as root and especially not running desktop applications as root.  root is for installing and removing and upgrading software, as well as other systems administration and maintenance tasks.

Comment: you do realise that `du -hs /root/*` won't include any files/folders in `/root` that start with `.` - you could try `du -hs /root/* /root/.??*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the **ghost trash folder** in this extra account. When you open Disk Usage Analyzer as a regular user you see a mismatch between the space occupied and what is shown in next screen. In the image below is shown a partition with 48.9 GB and with only 5.7 GB free.

[image]

but when you click in the `/` folder the screen shown only 21.6 GB of space used and no information about `/root/` folder.

[image]

Opening Disk Usage Analyzer from the terminal as a superuser you can actually see what's inside the `root` folder, and you'll find a **ghost trash folder** full of files that you deleted some time ago and that somehow went into this ghost folder that doesn't get emptied.

```
su
baobab /root/
```

[image]

You can empty this ghost folder with the command below in superuser mode

```
rm -r /root/.local/share/Trash/files/*
```

and problem solved!

[image]

Comment: no, the problem is that you logged in as root and used it as if it was a normal user account.  don't do that.